# Making a Navigation Bar using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web page with a navigation bar at the top that I want to appear to change colors when you mouse over it by changing to a different file that is that image in a different color. I want to make a function that will create the HTML code for this bar. I started on it but I am confused as where to go from here.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
        function NavigationBar() {

            var reg1 = new Image
            var red1 = new Image

            reg1.src = "1.gif"
            red1.src = "1R.gif"

            onMouseOver = "document.thereg1.src=red1.src"
            onMouseOut = "document.thereg1.src=reg1.src"
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="Home Page.html" NavigationBar(thereg1)>
        <img src="1.gif" Name="thereg1">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean the bar colour or the link background colour? Regardless, both can be done with CSS, javascript is probably overkill

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use Javascript for that

Just stick with CSS because it really easier and do like this :

```
link {

background-image: url ...
}

link:hover{
background-image: ..
transition : background-image 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

this will just change the image on hover

IF you want to have a nice transition use transition